# How to see data-path if it was shortened in tooltip?

Tags: python

How to see data-path if it was shortened in tooltip?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either right click on the property and choose the option *Copy Data Path*, or if that doesn't work try gratuitously changing a value even if for the same setting.

Then check the *Info* window history for the full name, you can copy it from there by selecting the line and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Yea, but if it's uneditable and unchangeable? :)  https://imgur.com/K2f22kr

Comment: Blender still lets you edit most greyed out values even if they are innactive, and they still correctly register at the *Info* window. If not use the copy data path method.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Might worth to mention that as of 2.79 you can copy the *full* data path to the clipboard as well `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C`.

Comment: @brockmann Yep, but strangely it seems to not be working for the Transform Orientations case, probably because of the dropdown menu