# Is there a way to stop Blender from replacing part of a Python Tooltip with an ellipsis?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

If you have Python tooltips enabled you will be able to see the property type and datapath by hovering over something like a button or similar:

[image: a picture showing a python tooltip]

However, in some cases Blender replaces parts of the datapath with an ellipsis:

[image: a picture showing how part of a datapath was replaced with an ellipis in a tooltip]

(In this case the actual datapath is `bpy.data.objects["Subdiv Plane"].vertex_groups.active_index`)

**My Question: Is there a way to stop Blender from replacing parts of a datapath with an ellipsis?**

I know that there are some ways to manually investigate what the ellipsis could stand for in a given example (and I also know how to use them), but disabling ellipses altogether would save the time needed for those investigations.

Comment: AFAIK no. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160824/blender-python-and-pass-settings  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95300/how-to-see-data-path-if-it-was-shortened-in-tooltip

Comment: Thanks, I seem to have missed that second post of yours.